# Make Card (or Paper) NOT take up full width Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a card element that does NOT span the entire width of the container it is in.

The [Example](https://material-ui.com/demos/cards/) seems to be able to do it fine

[image]

But when I attempt to use the example code, my card stretches the whole width of the page.

https://codesandbox.io/s/074zmkx0

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi when I ran your example it *also spans the entire page*, but this is an easy fix. Within your *Style.css* you can add a *css selector* to change your Card component's display to be `inline-block`.

**Style.css**

```
    /* Card component */
    #root > div > div {
          display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I think a more specific solution would be adding `style={{display: 'inline-block'}}` to the `Card` element.

Comment: I would separate your css into another file, in general I wouldn't use inline-styles. You can also do what you mentioned if you only want the card to be inline-block. Looking at your example I figured you wanted the headings to span the same width :)

Comment: Yeah, you can definitely separate it into another file, but that wasn't the point. Anyway, I appreciate the help. `inline-block` was all I needed. However, I feel like your edit now doesn't quite convey the correct answer and has a little too much information. I think the answer should just be short and sweet: add `inline-block` to the card element

Comment: np glad I was able to help, I will edit the answer as well

Comment: i would recommend to use flex-grow: 1, to keep the display type of material-ui(which is flex)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to apply the inline-block solution, a clean way is to wrap the card inside a box

```
<Box display="inline-block">
    <Card...
</Box>
```

Answer (score -5):

Use sizing:

```
import { sizing } from '@material-ui/system';

card :{
    width:"50%"
}
```

For more information: https://material-ui.com/system/sizing/